# Slick Carousel Responsive Feature not Working

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass, slick.js

These are the settings for the slick carousel I'm using on my page

```
  $('.service-carousel').slick({
   dots: false,
   infinite: true,
   speed: 300,
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: true,
   autoplay: true,
   autoplaySpeed: 2000,
   responsive: [{
   breakpoint: 1200,
   settings: {
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   infinite: true
  }
 },
 {
   breakpoint: 600,
   settings: {
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   infinite: true
  }
 }]
});
```

This is my html

```
<div class="sixth-slide">
  <p class="title">EYES</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row vertical-container text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12 content cooo text-center">
        <div class="service-carousel">
          <div><img src="img/eyeone.png" class="eyelogos" /></div>
          <div><img src="img/eyetwo.png" class="eyelogos" /></div>
          <div><img src="img/eyethree.png" class="eyelogos" /></div>
          <div><img src="img/eyefour.png" class="eyelogos" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-scroll"><a href="#" class="bottom"><img src="img/godown.png" class="godown"/></a></div>
</div>
```

And My CSS(SASS)

```
.vertical-container
   min-height: 100vh
   display: -webkit-box
   display: -moz-box
   display: -ms-flexbox
   display: -webkit-flex
   display: flex
   -webkit-box-align : center
   -webkit-align-items : center
   -moz-box-align : center
   -ms-flex-align : center
   align-items : center
   width: 100%
   -webkit-box-pack : center
   -moz-box-pack : center
   -ms-flex-pack : center
   -webkit-justify-content : center
   justify-content : center
   position: relative

.content.cooo
   display: block
   text-align: center
   margin: 0 auto
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif

div.sixth-slide
  .div.row.vertical-container
     @extend .vertical-container
  .eyelogos
     width: 60%
     margin-left: 20%
```

It's meant to give me a vertically and horizontally centered, responsive carousel. The only issue is when I resize or reload the page on a screen less than 992px wide, the carousel becomes 5965230px wide and it just completely messes up my page not to mention the items in the carousel become invisible, I tried Owl carousel and was getting a similar problem and now Slick too. Can any one tell me where I went wrong or possibly suggest a better responsive carousel?

Comment: even i worked on that slick slider today. what a coincidence.. i'll try to solve

Comment: can you tell me what is the size of the images you are using

Comment: The size is there. They're the "eyelogos" class. I tried to make the size responsive by styling it relative to the width of one slideItem, so it contains 60% of the item width and the height is automatic to preserve the aspect ratio. I gave it a margin-left of 20% so that it will be centered within the slideItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue you are facing is through CSS

change the css and try

```
.vertical-container
```

this class CSS is causing that issue, iam not sure, but i think `display:flex;` don't work.

hope this helps..

Comment: That almost fixed the error, but I think I can hack the little overflow here with jQuery and CSS, but why do you suppose it was working for screens above 991px but not below it? Besides I gave the row class a display of flex, not the carousel itself....

Comment: @EricMcWinNer as i said iam not sure what causing it to work on big screens, but i could figure out that was a css issue in small screens..

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. Guess I have to find another way to vertically center the carousel.

Answer (score 0):

```
use below arguments please

$('.service-carousel').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
```

Comment: It didn't fix the problem prashant. The "slick-track" class is still super wide. I even tried reducing the size of the track class with javascript, but the items still remain invisible...

Comment: JQuery lightSlider (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html) use this one.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having issues with slides not displaying correctly on smaller viewports, try giving Slick some boundaries to work with:

```
.slick-list {
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```